# Can't read in any characters with scanf

Tags: c, scanf

I have written a program that reads in an integer, a floating point number and a character and outputs it formatted. However, it doesn't quite work because I can't read in any characters if I start the program.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int a;
    float b;
    char c;

    scanf("%d", &a);
    scanf("%f", &b);
    scanf("%s", &c);

    printf("%-14s: %010d\n", "Ganzzahlen", a);
    printf("%-14s: %5.5f\n", "Gleitkommazahl", b);
    printf("%-14s: %c\n", "Zeichen", c);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `%s` for strings and `%c` for characters.

Comment: Use `"%s"` for continguous non-whitespace "strings". Use `" %c"` (notice leading SP) to discard whitespace ahead of the single character expected...

Comment: Use `%c` for one single character and `%s` for an array of `char`s (declared as `char** s;`) aka string.

Comment: @TheEagle `%s` reads a string, not an array. Using `char **` with it would be wrong .

Comment: @Yanic Hermann, post an example of input used.

Comment: @M.M huh ? how would a string be represented in C then, if not as an array of `char*` ?

Comment: @TheEagle As an array of `char`

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments, you want to use the correct format specifier for the type. For a single character, the correct specifier is `%c`.

However, that will read *any* character, so use `" %c"` with a leading space so that `scanf` ignores leading whitespace before the character. Without this, the space after your previous input has been read is still in the buffer and is immediately read.

You should also get in the habit of checking the return of `scanf` to make sure the correct number of values were read in.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` is named as that because it is a **scan**ner. It was not written to consume data from the keyboard, a free-form input. `scanf` was written to consume tabular data, things like giant `csv` files.
In these files each line is called a record and contains fields separated by a delimiter, being a comma the standard one. `csv` stands for comma separated values. As an example, here `"%d %f %2s"` uses `space` as the delimiter. `"%d:%f:%2s` sets the use of `:`.

- `scanf` skips white space, like spaces tabs --- and newlines depending on the specifier.
- `scanf` stops as soon as the specifier is satisfied or the line ends.
- it is normal to read nothing. It is a scanner anyway. For this reason `scanf` returns an `int` with the total of values read, or a negative value in case of error.
- you need to consume the '\n' that ended each `scanf` call, or it will interfere with the next `scanf` calls in your code
- a call to `printf` clears `stdin` buffer
- to read a single char is problematic since `stdio` is buffered anyway
- consider using `fgets()` to consume each line and then feeding the lines to `sscanf()`. In general it is easier to control keyboard input this way
- if the fields are read one at a time you can convert them using `atoi()` or `atod()` and skip the use of these scanners entirely: they were not written for this use (keyboard input) anyway. The advantage of using `scanf()` is that you can read a line of delimited input and convert all fields to mixed types in one call.

#### output of the example

```
   Please enter an integer: 42
   1 value(s) read: Ganzzahlen    : 0000000042
   Please enter a float number: 42.42
   1 value(s) read: Gleitkommazahl: 42.42000
   Please enter a char: one call
   1 value(s) read: Zeichen       : o
```

#### code

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int   a;
    float b;
    char  c[80];
    int   res = 0;

    printf("\n    Please enter an integer: ");
    res = scanf("%i", &a);
    printf("    %d value(s) read: ", res);
    if (res == 1) printf("%-14s: %010d\n", "Ganzzahlen", a);

    printf("    Please enter a float number: ");
    res = scanf("%f", &b);
    printf("    %d value(s) read: ", res);
    if (res == 1) printf("%-14s: %5.5f\n", "Gleitkommazahl", b);

    printf("    Please enter a char: ");
    res = scanf("%2s", &c);
    printf("    %d value(s) read: ", res);
    if (res == 1) printf("%-14s: %c\n", "Zeichen", c[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s, &c)` should be `scanf("%19s", c)`

Comment: removed the one call/3 values input for now. I have no time to change and also edit the answer to explain the use of oher functions, like `FlushConsoleInputBuffer()` or `fgets()` /``sscanf``calls. Hope it can still be useful reduced this way. Maybe tomorrow I add a new example

Comment: @Fe203 :) Really?  It was never so true. With BI and AI giant data sources are now available even for the public in general. On a global scale try  [Data World](https://data.world/resources/) or [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets). For a not so global one try [catalog.data.gov](https://catalog.data.gov) with more than a quarter of a million of _csv_ available datasets. This one was the latest I used: https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/crime-data-from-2020-to-present and has over 800,000 lines

Comment: try `scanf` wih the 800,000 lines dataset I cited. You can have a surprise.

Comment: @Fe203 this line you posted is a simple toy. To insert the delimiter of the CSV inside a quoted field has no meaning. Try browsing some public databases and you will see what is available today. In "Global" or "local" sets... There is no de facto standard for csv just because it preceds the internet and the W3C and IETF. But see [RFC4180](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt) and you can learn something

Comment: @Fe203 anyway what we do here to import possibly malformed folcloric stuff like this, using `C` and `csv` is to simply parse the lines and escape the delimiters found inside quoted fields. It is the same with the first line of a csv, that can have the field names. You can find instructions on this to import files into Oracle, MySQL, SQL server, Google Cloud, Sheets, Excel, whatever: all this things import and export csv files and can fail, as `scanf` can. But this case is trivial.

Comment: "Trivial"? Then it should be simple. Rather than dismissing and avoiding, please compose a "trivial" scanf() format string that would handle `12:30,"37,58"\n13:00.40\n` as two temperature readings exported from a Google Sheets workbook. Your answer claims "_scanf was written to consume tabular data, things like giant csv files._"

Comment: @Fe203, may be I did not explained well. It is just a comment. There is always some type of sanitizing on the input, if you are not sure it the file is well formed. As I told you, the first line is always problematic, since it can not be data. As an example, even for databases, you need to be sure if the data is escaped or not, which is the delimiter and such. If a field is escaped (quoted) them *all* fields need to be. See for example [gcloud sql import csv](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/import-export-csv)

Comment: @FE203 the `scanf` thing, is simple and trivial. Post a question. And this thing you posted is not even valid. Anyway, the usual is to run some sanitizing function, like we do with html, and the first thing this function do is to escape all fields. The first line is always inspected in search for field names. . . And so on. Do you know that Google Sheets has an export function? Use `File|Download` and see if you can export such a thing as you showed above :D. Hint: you will have a `csv` file with escaped fields.... Try. You can learn something

Comment: Perhaps you missed it. The sample provided **WAS** downloaded (as CSV) from Google Sheets (extended to show the two `'\n'`)... You try it. You can learn something! It is your erroneous claim regarding `scanf()` (and other statements) that are "_not even valid_". Suggest you correct the several mistaken claims made in this answer. (I have no need to post a question about this. I understand the CSV file format and the limitations of `scanf()`...)

Comment: ? extended? Funny comments! The command in Sheets is just File | Download (as csv). Try to validate your `csv` thing against an online validating tool. There are many.

Comment: Such arrogance... Oh well... Another bad answer from you...